# Memory usage change very fast, is it normal?

Tags: java, memory-management

I just wonder, is it normal that memory usage is changing so fast.

I run this [code](http://www.brackeen.com/javagamebook/)  It is tutorial 'How to make a simple game.'

I add some code in main loop of the game:

```
g.setColor(Color.cyan);
g.drawString(System.currentTimeMillis() + "\n\n/nRAM:[" + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / 1024 / 1024 + " MB]", 100, 100);
```

The RAM usage is changing very fast between 25-30 and so on,

My question is why is it happens ? Is it wrong behavior or it doesnt matter ? Is the code wrong written ?

EDIT:
Im suspicious because for example on this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3buRQz5UorU)  memory usage is stable, moreover the  brackeen game have same usage (25mb) until the sound stop's playing.

Comment: Computers are really fast.  Don't worry about it unless there is an upwards trend over a long time.

Comment: No it's not wrong. Massive increases, none left and always going up are probably wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, memory management is handled automatically by a garbage collector. So, once an object is no longer needed (there are no references left to it), it doesn't get free'd right away, but instead stays in the memory. Every now and then (depending on several factors, like JVM settings, maximum heap sizes etc.), the garbage collection kicks in and removes the unneeded objects. Since this doesn't happen every frame, you see the memory usage climbing, and then drop suddenly as the garbage collection has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

If you create lots of garbage, you can see it producing 500 MB per second or more.

If you use a memory profiler you can reduce memory consumption and it can drop to less than 1 MB per minute for a running program.

Comment: Yep, but when you take code called 'Basic game tutorial' there should be warranty that there is no massive leaks :/

Comment: Creating garbage is not the same as a memory leak (memory which cannot be recovered)